# Files in "Revert to" stored?

Tags: macos, filesystem

If I store a (for example) Numbers file on a USB flash drive, will all the previous versions of that file also be stored on the same flash drive (File > Revert To > Browse All Versions)? Or are all the previous versions stored on the local Mac OS drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored on the flash drive, in the hidden folder `/.DocumentRevisions-V100`.